# can we detect a key is pressed in fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am developing an application in which I want to do some thing when a key is pressed. Can we implement in the fragments.

I do not want to do anything in the activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect this in the `Activity` your `Fragment` is a part of. `Fragments` are part of `Activity`, not vice versa.

Comment: Actually Activity is not in my scope. I am just giving an api to attach fragment with a particular activity. so I want to implemets key listener in fragments.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you show a peace of code where you go this attachment?